# Accessing Radio Button Values in DataTable (Shiny)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, radio-button, dt

I am having trouble accessing radio button input values when they're imbedded in a DataTable in shiny. I am basing my code of off this example: [Radio Buttons in DT](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/)

It accesses the values on the first pass and displays them underneath as seen in the following screenshot:
[First pass screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STy3D.jpg)

Once I change an input that reactively re-renders the table, the values from the radio buttons are no longer displayed and are instead stuck on the first pass values. This can be seen in the following screenshot.
[Second pass screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl0X9.jpg)

After the first pass, the inputs are no longer updated to reflect the radio button selection. The original inputs seem to freeze and I can't find a way to access the current button values.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Here is the code for the above example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    selectInput('questions','Pick',c(1,2)),
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    myData = reactiveValues(m = NULL)
    temp = month.abb
    
    observeEvent(input$questions,{
      m = data.table(
        
        
        month1 = temp[1:5],
        A = '1',
        B = '2',
        C = '3',
        QWE = runif(5)
      )
      m[, A := sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        month1, m[, A]
      )]
      m[, B := sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        month1, m[, B]
      )]
      m[, C := sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        month1, m[, C]
      )]
      
      myData$m = m
    })
    
    
    
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable({
      m = myData$m
      print(m)
      
    }
    , escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE, rownames=FALSE,
    options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
    callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                  var $this = $(this.node());
                  $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                  $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
  });
                  Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                  Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      str(sapply(month.abb, function(i) input[[i]]))
    })
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are resetting `m` inside the `observeEvent()`.  If you define it outside the observer, it works as expected.  Try this

```
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    myData <- reactiveValues(m = NULL)
    temp <- month.abb
    m <- data.table(
      month1 = temp[1:5],
      A = '1',
      B = '2',
      C = '3',
      QWE = runif(5)
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$questions,{
     
      m[, A := sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        month1, m[, A]
      )]
      m[, B := sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        month1, m[, B]
      )]
      m[, C := sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        month1, m[, C]
      )]
      
      myData$m = m
    })
    
    
    
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable({
      m = myData$m
      print(m)
      
    }
    , escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE, rownames=FALSE, # editable=TRUE,
    options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
    callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                  var $this = $(this.node());
                  $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                  $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
     });
                  Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                  Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    
    
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      str(sapply(month.abb, function(i) input[[i]]))
    })
  }
```