# Radio Button in reactive DT datatable: problem accessing input after refreshing

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, radio-button, dt

I have a reactive table, which needs to be rendered as a DT datatable with some radio buttons.
It's similar to [this code](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-radio/) but with a reactive table.

However, whenever the table is recalculated (refreshed), the inputs stop being updated with new clicks.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(shinycssloaders)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    actionButton('refresca', 'Refresh'),
    withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput('foo')),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    m <-
      reactive({

        m <-
          data.table(
            month1 = month.abb,
            A = '1',
            B = '2',
            C = '3',
            QWE = runif(12)
          )

        m %>%
          mutate(across(c('A', 'B', 'C'), \(x) glue('<input type="radio" name="{month1}" value="{x}"/>')))

      }) %>% bindEvent(input$refresca)

    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      {
        m = m()
        print(m)

      }, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE, rownames=FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE)
      ,callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                    var $this = $(this.node());
                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
  });
                    Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                    Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )

    output$sel = renderPrint({
      str(sapply(month.abb, function(i) input[[i]]))
    })
  }
)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66179160/accessing-radio-button-values-in-datatable-shiny?rq=1) is similar, but their table is not reactive. Putting the table outside reactiveness solved their problem, but I can't do that in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unbind before refreshing. Since the refreshing is triggered by a click on the `refresca` button, you can unbind when a click occurs; use this callback:

```r
      "
      table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                    var $this = $(this.node());
                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
      });
      $('#refresca').on('click', function() {
        Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
      });
      Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
      Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());
      "
```